# Magento 2 showing the same Widget twice

Tags: magento2, widgets, widget

I need to create 2 widgets on the homepage (CMS Home Page -> Main Content Area).

To do that, I created 2 modules (one for each widget) and extended them from Catalog Product List to use my own template (and also to select the products from the admin in a more fancy way).

The problem is that the frontend is displaying the same widget twice (the first one, the other one doesn't appear at all).

Apparently, there is a [known issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4389) related to this, but if someone found a solution to this bug and share it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of magento 2 are you using?

Comment: @AndréFerraz 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution and forgot to post it here, better late than never. The issue is that the widget_id isn't stored within the cache key, so I added the `getCacheKeyInfo` method to the Block of my Module and set the id for the widget (note `self::WIDGET_ID`).

```
/*
 * Set widget id to prevent M2 bug
 * https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4389
 */
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
    return [
        'CATALOG_PRODUCTS_LIST_WIDGET',
        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
        $this->_design->getDesignTheme()->getId(),
        $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_GROUP),                intval($this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getData('page_var_name'), 1)),
        $this->getProductsPerPage(),
        self::WIDGET_ID,
        serialize($this->getRequest()->getParams())
    ];
}
```